# Uncrustify - How do I align trailing comments by two-space gap?

Tags: uncrustify

After I applied Atom Beautify on my code using Uncrustify, the trailing comments are aligned as follow:

```
unsigned int redLEDValue      = 0; // redLED
unsigned int blueLEDValue     = 0; // blueLED
unsigned int greenLEDValue    = 0; // greenLED
unsigned int redSensorValue   = 0; // redSensor
unsigned int blueSensorValue  = 0; // blueSensor
unsigned int greenSensorValue = 0; // greenSensor
```

There is only once space between the semicolon and the trailing comment, but I want to have at least 2 spaces between them. I'm using **Atom 1.12.9**, **Atom Beautify 0.29.16**, and **Uncrustify 0.64**. Here is [my Uncrustify config](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/philectron/1a1e1ccb06d5643cd61d85fc5ecaf429/raw/e13882345963361b11697f5b3cdddb8e01a918c7/uncrustify-preferences.cfg).

Is there any way to increase the gap? I've already set `align_right_cmt_span = 4` but no hope. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable adding spaces first with the option:

```
sp_before_tr_emb_cmt            = add
```

> sp_before_tr_emb_cmt: Controls the spaces before a trailing or
>   embedded comment

Than you can adjust the amount of spaces with:

```
sp_num_before_tr_emb_cmt        = 2
```

> sp_num_before_tr_emb_cmt: Number of spaces before a trailing or
>   embedded comment

---

**Edit:**

Uncrustify has also an aligning function for trailing comments which is applied after the spacing functionalities. The aligning function is controlled by those three options:

```
align_right_cmt_span            = 1        # unsigned number
```

> The span for aligning comments that end lines (0=don't align)

```
align_right_cmt_gap             = 10       # number
```

> If a trailing comment is more than this number of columns away from the text it follows,
>   it will qualify for being aligned. This has to be > 0 to do anything.
>   A negative value [will] force comments which are stuck to the previous token
>   (gap=0) into alignment with the others.

```
align_right_cmt_at_col          = 80       # unsigned number
```

> Align trailing comment at or beyond column N; 'pulls in' comments as a bonus side effect (0=ignore)

**Note:**

- The functionality is enabled if `align_right_cmt_span` is greater
  than 0.
- Contrary to its description `align_right_cmt_gap` is
  enabled if it is 0. All numeric options are initially set to 0 as default values.
- If `align_right_cmt_at_col` is less than the column of the last char before the beginning of the comment the comment will be indented to one space after the last char.

Comment: It does sound very good to me, but it didn't work on my system. Would you mind checking my config for me?
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/philectron/1a1e1ccb06d5643cd61d85fc5ecaf429/raw/8813567b8f7dd49003228e19c3d10719b49995a1/uncrustify-preferences.cfg

Comment: same with me. I tried this and it is not working on my uncrustify installation on osx.

Comment: using `sp_before_tr_emb_cmt = force` and `sp_num_before_tr_emb_cmt = 2` worked for me with uc `0.72.0`.