# uncrustify google style c++ config

Tags: atom-editor, uncrustify, cpplint, atom-beautify

I am using uncrustify and atom-beautify in atom.io to format my C++ code according to google styling guide. I am using CPPlint to verify whether the code is formatted correctly. I am using the config file from https://gist.githubusercontent.com/philectron/1a1e1ccb06d5643cd61d85fc5ecaf429/raw/8813567b8f7dd49003228e19c3d10719b49995a1/uncrustify-preferences.cfg. But after beautifying, cpplint is reporting the following problems.

1. "At least two spaces is best between code and comments [whitespace/comments]" is not enforced and I am getting this error in multiple places. The answer for this question at [Uncrustify - How do I align trailing comments by two-space gap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526950/uncrustify-how-do-i-align-trailing-comments-by-two-space-gap) is not working.
2. "protected: should be indented +1 space inside." I am getting the same error for private and public as well.

If this is not the right way, how can I beautify and lint inside atom.io.

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe I wasn't clear enough in the last answer or you haven't read it carefully enough. Here is another try.

Uncrustify has *spacing* and *aligning* functions. Aligning functions are applied after the spacing functions (at least in the case of the trailing comments).

If you have `align_right_cmt_span` set to greater than zero the aligning functions **will also** be applied on trailing comments. 
<s>The option `align_right_cmt_gap` is than enabled, even if it is set to zero, which it is by default even if you do **not** specify it.</s> It seems that it is now only active if it is not zero. Additionally to that problem you have `align_right_cmt_at_col` set to 1.

I am not using CPPlint, atom-beautify or the google styling guide. So if you want help, upload some code examples: input code, output code, expected code.